# +method may not respond

Tags: objective-c, class

My method may not respond and I can't get why

in ClassA.h:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject {
    NSString *inStr;
    NSInteger *peak;
}
@property (retain,nonatomic)      NSString *inStr;
@end
```

in ClassA.m

```
 NSLog(@"%d peaks",peak);
                       peak++;
                       inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Peaks : %d",peak ];

                       [ClassB setUpdateLabel:inStr];
```

in ClassB.h

```
    @interface ClassB : NSObject {
            IBOutlet UILabel *peaksLabel;
            NSString *tempStr;
        }

    @property (nonatomic, retain)   UILabel             *peaksLabel;
    - (void) setUpdateLabel:(NSString*)inStr;
    @end
```

in ClassB.m

```
#import ClassB.h
@implementation classB;
-(void) setUpdateLabel:(NSString*)inStr{
    peaksLabel.text=inStr;

}
```

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring  `- (void) setUpdateLabel:(NSString*)inStr;` as a instance method, however you are using it as a class method.

'-' indicates instance methods
'+' indicates class methods

If you want this to work you either change the declaration to `+ (void) setUpdateLabel:(NSString*)inStr;` or you make an object of the Class B like this:

```
ClassB *obj = [[ClassB alloc] init];
[obj setUpdateLabel:@"Something"];
```

and remember to release it.

Comment: But I can't access my peaksLabel.text that way

Answer (score 0):

- (void)setUpdateLabel is not a class method. Create an instance of classB and send the message to this instance.

  classB *instance = [[classB alloc] init];

  [instance setUpdateLabel:inStr];